# How to create the following binary file structure

Tags: c#, .net, binary, binaryfiles, file-format

I have a task to create the following binary file format structure but I don't know where to start and how to create it. Could you guys please point me out on the right direction? 
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You could use a FileStream (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and methods from BitConverter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: BinaryWriter would be a good place to start. *Unicode string* is quite a silly description without knowing the encoding..

Comment: Your question is arguably a set of requirements.  What have you researched?  What have  you tried?  Check out the Help page for some jolly good tips on how to ask a good question.  I wish you well!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the BinaryWriter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24e33k1w(v=vs.110).aspx). If your numeric values are to be stored in little endian, you can use the `Write` methods directly over a file stream. Otherwise you can do the following to first convert the values to big endian (example for a `int`, which has 4 bytes; for a 8 bytes `long` you would use `ToInt64`):

```
byte[] temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(theIntValue);
Array.Reverse(temp);
theIntValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp, 0);
```